# Connecting point without continus boundaries

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I want to plot trajectories, without connecting the points from boundaries. Attached an image of what i mean.

My code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# import polygon as poly
x, y = np.loadtxt('c55.txt', delimiter='    ', unpack=True)
    
plt.plot(x, y, '.' ,color = 'k' , markersize=0.5)
#for i in range(1, len(x),1):
 #if abs(x[i]-x[i+1])>300:
plt.plot(x,y,'-o',color='red',ms=5,label="Window 1")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your x-values go several times from low to high.  `plt.plot` connects all points in the order they are encountered in the `x` and `y` arrays.

The following approach firsts looks for the indices where the `x`-values start again (so, where the difference of successive x's isn't positive).
These indices are then used to draw the separate curves.

```py
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

# first create some test data a bit similar to the given ones.
x = np.tile(np.linspace(-3, 3, 20), 4)
y = np.cos(x) + np.repeat(np.linspace(-3, 3, 4), 20)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(15, 4))

# plotting the test data without change
axs[0].plot(x, y, '-o')

bounds = np.argwhere(np.diff(x) < 0).squeeze() # find the boundaries
bounds = np.concatenate([[0], bounds + 1, [len(x)]]) # additional boundaries for the first and last point
for b0, b1 in zip(bounds[:-1], bounds[1:]):
    axs[1].plot(x[b0:b1], y[b0:b1], '-o') # use '-ro' for only red curves

plt.show()
```

[image: separating curves]